# Scoped SCSS variables for themeing

Tags: css, sass

I have a set of palettes for different themes like so:

```
$primary: red; 
$secondary: blue;

.theme-2 { $primary: green; $secondary: yellow; }

//..
//some random scss file that has typography class names
.cool-text { color: $primary; }
```

Is it possible to make it so, whatever the class name applied to the container uses the variable palette colors defined for it?

Ex:

```
<div class="theme-2">
   <p class="cool-text"> cool </p> // should be green
</div>


<p class="cool-text"> cool </p> //should be red
```

Comment: modified the code snippet..please let us know what worked..we can also learn something from what you have achieved

Answer (score 1):

Because Sass variables are compiled before runtime, they cannot be context-sensitive, so the example you provided would not be possible.

Some helpful reading with alternate examples here: 
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-variable-scope-in-sass--cms-23498

And I'd read into native CSS variables, which can do exactly what you want and are gaining support in most browsers aside from IE/Edge: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: I don't think that's entirely accurate as variables are scoped and so variables can be defined within a selector and used instead just as the first article suggests and also as indicated in the other answer.

Comment: Those are local variables, but they're defined by specificity in the SCSS - not based on what classes their elements are within when the CSS is run (which is what OP was asking for, and which native CSS variables support). There are many workarounds and alternate solutions, but they're not the same thing.

Comment: Even with the local variables and specificity it can work. `.theme-2 .cool-text { color : green }` and `.cool-text { color: red }` can be achieved using `local variables` which is what the OP wanted. I agree there are many workarounds and I'm saying that it is possible using local variables and scope. It might not be the best solution but it's doable. I'm also interested as how you would use the Css variables to achieve what the OP wants, could you explain?

Comment: Check out the section on here entitled "The cascade" for an example of how CSS variables achieves what the OP wants: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/css-variables-why-should-you-care#the_cascade

Comment: That's actually pretty neat! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use !default here
check this running code snippet,with your html [codepen](http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/zowqpN)

```
$primary: red !default; 
$secondary:blue !default;

.cool-text { color: $primary; }

.theme-2 { 
    $primary: green; 
    $secondary: yellow; 

    .cool-text{
      color: $primary;
    }
}
```

With this if color is not set to anything ,it would take default red color if not whatever you set it would take that

Hope it helps

Comment: You don't actually need the **!default** keyword. The variables defined outside the code block are **global** and the ones defined within the block are **local**. They are not the same so the !default keyword doesn't really make a difference here.

Comment: but whatever OP has asked can be achieved through this default keyword right?can you explain what can be the right approach for this...Want to learn

Comment: You achieved it without the `!default` keyword. `!default` means use this value if the variable isn't **redefined**. And the global variable is never _redefined_ because the ones in the selector are local so they aren't the same.